# Why is partial-rendering failing in this particular case?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I am using `Mojarra 2.2`.

Here the snippet:

```
    <h:head>
        <title></title>          
    </h:head> 
    <h:body> 
        <h:form id="playersFormId">                        
            <h:dataTable id="playersTableId" 
                         value="#{ajaxBean.myMap.entrySet()}" var="t">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Delete
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:commandLink id="commandDeleteId" 
                                   immediate="true" 
                                   action="#{ajaxBean.deletePlayerAction(t.key)}">

                        <f:ajax  render=":playersFormId:playersTableId"/>

                        <h:graphicImage value="/resources/default/imgs/delete.png"/>                            
                    </h:commandLink>     
                </h:column> 
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Nr
                    </f:facet>
                    #{t.key}             
                </h:column> 
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Name
                    </f:facet>
                    #{t.value}
                </h:column>                
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>            
    </h:body>
```

with

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class AjaxBean implements Serializable {

    private Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        myMap.put(1, "Nadal Rafael");
        myMap.put(2, "Federer Roger");
        myMap.put(3, "Ferer David");
        myMap.put(4, "Murray Andy");
        myMap.put(5, "Djokovic Novak");
        myMap.put(6, "Berdych Tomas");
        myMap.put(7, "Haas Tommy");
        myMap.put(8, "Isner John");
        myMap.put(9, "Fognini Fabio");
        myMap.put(10, "Robredo Tommy");
    }

    public Map<Integer, String> getMyMap() {
        return myMap;
    }

    public void setMyMap(Map<Integer, String> myMap) {
        this.myMap = myMap;
    }

    public void deletePlayerAction(String nr) {  
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
          ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
          Map<String, String> headers = externalContext.getRequestHeaderMap();


          //determination method 1       
          PartialViewContext partialViewContext =    
                            facesContext.getPartialViewContext();
          if (partialViewContext != null) {
            if (partialViewContext.isAjaxRequest()) {
                 System.out.println("THIS IS AN AJAX REQUEST (DETERMINATION 1) ...");
            } else {
                  System.out.println("THIS IS A NON-AJAX REQUEST(DETERMINATION 1)...");
            }
          }
        System.out.println("nr: "+nr);
        if(nr!=null){               
            myMap.remove(Integer.valueOf(nr));
        }
    }

}
```

I see that when i click on the image link, the server-side action method is getting c/d and the record is removed from the map. 
I have specified that the datatable needs to be refreshed, but it doesn't get so.

Where am I getting it wrong?

When I click on the first record, under Network Tab, I see-
[image]

& under Console Tab-

[image]

Comment: With "partial rendering failing", did you mean that the ajax response didn't at all contain the datatable? Or did you mean that it threw an exception? Or did you mean that the `myMap` still contains the supposedly removed entry? (and thus it's actually not the partial rendering itself which failed as the view merely presents the model as it is)

Comment: @BalusC: I mean neither. As seen, render contains the :playersFormId:playersTableId. Amazingly, it works if I nest f:ajax along with event=click inside the graphic image.

Comment: @BalusC: For the problem above, the entry gets removed from the map(suppose initially there were 10 items, now its 9), but when the page is re-rendered, it remains as it is(shows up all the ten after the Ajax request). Could you suggest something in this regard?

Comment: @BalusC: Please help. I see under Network tab in Google Chrome, javax.faces.partial.execute:playersFormId:playersTableId:6:commandDeleteId 
javax.faces.partial.render:playersFormId:playersTableId:6, when I delete the 7th record. I have absolutely no idea why it is rendering javax.faces.partial.render:playersFormId:playersTableId:6 instead of javax.faces.partial.render:playersFormId:playersTableId

Comment: I can't answer from top of head based on information provided so far as the described behavior is unexpected. I'd have to create a reproducer myself based on information provided so far and verify/debug it myself.

Comment: @BalusC: Thank you so much. Even a comment from your end matters a lot to me.(or else HOPE IN ITSELF IS A DANGEROUS THING). Now all the information is included. When you have sufficient time, please do verify it. One more thing, when I put render="@form", it works perfectly.

Comment: So far it looks like a bug in Mojarra.

Comment: @BalusC: Yes, it is a bug in Mojarra 2.2 version. It's works perfectly in Apache MyFaces 2.2 version. I mean the same exact code.